# Why is the `dataTransfer` method returning null for my objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a drag and drop application using React and I'm following this tutorial: https://jsfiddle.net/xv5mu40h/8/.

However, when I try it on my end, I get this error message:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of null`, talking specifically about this line of code: `const nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);`.

I've console logged what `data` is before this line of code and it appears that `data` is null when I try to drag and drop any of the objects (which I call rewards in this case). Any help is appreciated!

NOTE: I've taken out as much of the irrelevant code as possible; for more focus points, I believe that the problem lies in the dragging/dropping function (not in any of the lifecycle methods or the unique identifier method).

```
class Home extends Component {
  // Constructor for home
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rewards: [],
      cat1Counter: 1,
      cat2Counter: 1,
      cat3Counter: 1,
      cat4Counter: 1,
      cat5Counter: 1
    };
  }

  // Fetch rewards once component mounts
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchRewards();
  }

  // Update local state once all rewards are fetched
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.rewards !== prevProps.rewards) this.setState({rewards: this.props.rewards});
  }

  // Creates a unique ID for a reward copy
  getUniqueId(prefix) {
    let id = '';
    if (prefix === 'reward-1') {
      id = `${prefix} copy-${this.state.cat1Counter++}`
    } else if (prefix === 'reward-2') {
      id = `${prefix} copy-${this.state.cat2Counter++}`
    } else if (prefix === 'reward-3') {
      id = `${prefix} copy-${this.state.cat3Counter++}`
    } else if (prefix === 'reward-4') {
      id = `${prefix} copy-${this.state.cat4Counter++}`
    } else if (prefix === 'reward-5') {
      id = `${prefix} copy-${this.state.cat5Counter++}`
    }

    return id;
  }

  // Allow for elements to be dropped in other elements
  allowDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  // Removes a node
  removeNode(node) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }

  // Drags a reward
  drag(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text', e.target.id);
  }

  // Drops the reward
  drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    const isLeft = 'reward-1' === data || 'reward-2' === data;

    const nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    nodeCopy.id = `${this.getUniqueId(data)}`;

    if (isLeft) {
      e.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    } else {
      if (e.target.id !== 'P') {
        this.removeNode(document.getElementById(data));
        e.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
      }
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="home-container">
        <div className="rewards-container">
          <h2>Rewards</h2>

          <ul>
            {this.state.rewards.map(reward => <li key={reward._id} draggable onDragStart={e => this.drag(e)}>{reward.name}</li>)}
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="categories-container">
          <h2>Categories</h2>

          <div className="list-wrapper">
            <ul id="category-1" onDrop={e => this.drop(e)} onDragOver={e => this.allowDrop(e)}><p>C1</p></ul>
            <ul id="category-2" onDrop={e => this.drop(e)} onDragOver={e => this.allowDrop(e)}><p>C2</p></ul>
            <ul id="category-3" onDrop={e => this.drop(e)} onDragOver={e => this.allowDrop(e)}><p>C3</p></ul>
            <ul id="category-4" onDrop={e => this.drop(e)} onDragOver={e => this.allowDrop(e)}><p>C4</p></ul>
            <ul id="category-5" onDrop={e => this.drop(e)} onDragOver={e => this.allowDrop(e)}><p>C5</p></ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

**UPDATE**

Per the answer below, I've changed `onDrag` to `onDragStart` and now it works when I drag objects from the rewards list into the categories; however, the bug still pops up when I try dragging cloned objects in between categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the data onDragStart. The onDrag would be called every time you drag and might be not the right place to set . You could change onDrag to onDragStart

Comment: Thank you! This solves half of the problem, now the bug only pops up when I try dragging cloned objects in between categories (i.e. from C1 to C2, etc.)

Comment: I assumed that cloned objects would also have the same event listeners, which I believe it does because it gets all the way to the drop function, but if it also goes through the drag function, shouldn't `dataTransfer.getData` have the correct object id? Maybe my understanding of `setData` and `dataTransfer` is a bit wrong...

Comment: The new node that is created, this should not be through DOM clone. The react might not able to attach onDragStart events properly. This should bet through react

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense; would you happen to have a good tutorial on cloning with react?

Comment: You can initial an array in the state and use it to create the list of Drop Targets using map. For cloning you could change the array and set the state. This would reflect in the React DOM.

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-use-the-key-prop-when-rendering-a-list-with-react-12564a86 May be this will help.

Comment: Thank you! I just finished watching the video; it's a great explanation on keys and making a list of elements! However I'm still a bit confused on the cloning part; when you say change the array, do you mean the array of drop targets? (the list of rewards that clones are dragged from)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214196/discussion-between-vishnu-sandhireddy-and-karen).